# collect a multivariate polynomial, and simplify all coefficients

Tags: polynomials, coefficients

I have a polynomial like this:

> (a x + b c y + d z) (d x + e c y + g z)

I would like to rewrite it as something like this:

> a d x^2 + b c^2 e y^2 + d g z^2 + (c (b d + a e)) x y + (d^2 + a g) x z + (c (d e + b g)) y z

i.e. keep all terms of different variables separate, collect all the coefficients for each term, and also simplify all the coefficients. How can we do this?

`Collect` gives a nested collection, so it is not what I want.

(i.e. it gives this:

```
a d x^2 + b c^2 e y^2 + (c d e + b c g) y z + d g z^2 + x ((b c d + a c e) y + (d^2 + a g) z)
```

where the last term is a nested one)

The closest I can find is

```
expr=(a x + b c y + d z) (d x + e c y + g z);

Plus @@ MonomialList[Expand[expr], {x, y, z}]
```

which collects all the coefficients but refuses to simplify them, i.e.

```
a d x^2 + (b c d + a c e) x y + b c^2 e y^2 + (d^2 + a g) x z + (c d e + b c g) y z + d g z^2.
```

Comment: See [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect#58357)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possibility:

```
Activate @ Expand @ Collect[
    (a x+b c y+d z) (d x+e c y+g z),
    {x, y, z},
    Inactive[Simplify]
]
```

> a d x^2 + c (b d + a e) x y + b c^2 e y^2 + (d^2 + a g) x z + 
>    c (d e + b g) y z + d g z^2

Answer (score 4):

```
expr = (a x + b c y + d z) (d x + e c y + g z);

Simplify /@ Total @ MonomialList[Expand[expr], {x, y, z}]
Total[Simplify /@ MonomialList[Expand[expr], {x, y, z}]]
```

or, a variation on Carl's approach (change the order of `Collect` and `Expand`)

```
Expand[Collect[(a x + b c y + d z) (d x + e c y + g z), {x, y, z}, foo]]/. foo -> Simplify
```

all give

> a d x^2 + c (b d + a e) x y + b c^2 e y^2 + (d^2 + a g) x z +  c (d e + b g) y z + d g z^2

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear exactly what you seek, but this seems close:

```
Collect[Expand[(a x + b c y + d z) (d x + e c y + g z)], {x, y, z}]
```

Comment: `Collect` gives a nested collection, which is not what I want.

Comment: When your question says you're seeking "something like this" it is manifest you're not being clear and precise.  I don't think we can help you without a detailed, precise specification of what you seek.

Comment: What I want is stated after the second highlighted expression, after "i.e.". I used "something like this" because the exact order of the terms and variables, as well as the parentheses around the common coefficient `c`, does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approached using `CoefficientRules` and `CoefficientList`:

```
poly = (a x + b c y + d z) (d x + e c y + g z);

cr = Simplify@CoefficientRules[poly, {x, y, z}];
(x^#1 y^#2 z^#3 & @@@ #[[;; , 1]]).#[[;; , 2]] &@cr

cl = Simplify@CoefficientList[poly, {x, y, z}];
Total@Flatten[Array[x^#1 y^#2 z^#3 &, {3, 3, 3}, {0, 0, 0}] cl]
```

Both of which output

> a d x^2 + c (b d + a e) x y + b c^2 e y^2 + (d^2 + a g) x z + c (d e
>   + b g) y z + d g z^2