# Collect terms in a polynomial, distributed

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

Consider the following expression

```
in = a x^2 y + 2 x z + b z x + c x^2 y + x ;
```

I would like to collect terms in $(x,y,z)$ in a distributive way, that is

```
out = (a+c) x^2 y + (2+b) x z + x;
```

I tried the following command

```
Collect[expr,{x,y,z}]
Collect[expr,{x,y,z},Factor]
Collect[expr,{x,y,z},Simplify]
```

But here is the output:

> Out[2]= (a + c) x^2  y + x (1 + (2 + b) z)
>
> Out[3]= (a + c) x^2  y + x (1 + (2 + b) z)
>
> Out[4]= (a + c) x^2  y + x (1 + (2 + b) z)

Comment: Try this: `Collect[expr, {z, x, y}]`.

Comment: Ok it will work on this example, but I would like a generic way for general examples.
In fact I am looking for the Maple's equivalent to collect(expr,[x,y,z],'distributed');

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152362/collect-a-multivariate-polynomial-and-simplify-all-coefficients

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three ways you can go, using [`MonomialList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MonomialList.html), [`CoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientRules.html), [`FromCoefficientRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FromCoefficientRules.html) and [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html). The first is the simplest, but I've included the others because they're good to know about if you're dealing with polynomials a lot.

**1. `MonomialList`**

`MonomialList`will cut up your polynomial into the terms you want. So the simplest way is probably just:

```
poly = a x^2 y + 2 x z + b z x + c x^2 y + x;

Total@MonomialList[poly, {x, y, z}]

(* x + (a + c) x^2 y + (2 + b) x z *)
```

**2. `CoefficientRules` and `FromCoefficientRules`**

This method is slightly more convoluted than `MonomialList`, and so isn't really ideal in this situation. But it's well worth knowing that it can be done. `CoefficientRules` gets you the exponents and the corresponding coefficients, `FromCoefficientRules` reconstructs the polynomial with that form:

```
FromCoefficientRules[
 CoefficientRules[poly, {x, y, z}],
 {x, y, z}]

(* x + (a + c) x^2 y + (2 + b) x z *)
```

**3. `Collect` with `CoefficientRules`**

You can also get the monomials (power products) you want with

```
monomials = x^#1 y^#2 z^#3 & @@@ CoefficientRules[poly, {x, y, z}][[;; , 1]]

(* {x^2 y, x z, x} *)
```

Then `Collect` will do the job:

```
Collect[poly, monomials]

(* x + (a + c) x^2 y + (2 + b) x z *)
```

Just for reference, it's probably worth comparing that `monomials` list with the output from `MonomialList`, which is

```
MonomialList[poly, {x, y, z}]

(* {(a + c) x^2 y, (2 + b) x z, x} *)
```

That is, `monomials` just contains the power products, whereas `MonomialList` includes their coefficients. (Confusingly, [both can be called "monomials"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial)).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
expr = a x^2 y + 2 x z + b z x + c x^2 y + x;

lst = (Table[x^n*y^m*z^k, {n, 0, 2}, {m, 0, 1}, {k, 0, 1}] // 
    Flatten) /. x_ /; x == 1 -> Nothing

(*  {z, y, y z, x, x z, x y, x y z, x^2, x^2 z, x^2 y, x^2 y z}  *)
```

and then

```
Collect[expr, lst]

(*   x + (a + c) x^2 y + (2 + b) x z  *)
```

Have fun!